# Unplayable video produced from png frames

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to produce a video from .png files using

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i %04d.png -r 30 vid.mp4
```

but the output video refuses to play.  Any idea whats going wrong?  The report is:

```
unknown-4c:8d:79:e6:e3:fc:output robinedwards$ ffmpeg -f image2 -i %04d.png -r 30 vid.mp4
ffmpeg version 1.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May 14 2013 16:56:21 with Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.24) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/1.1.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=cc --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid
  libavutil      52. 13.100 / 52. 13.100
  libavcodec     54. 86.100 / 54. 86.100
  libavformat    54. 59.106 / 54. 59.106
  libavdevice    54.  3.102 / 54.  3.102
  libavfilter     3. 32.100 /  3. 32.100
  libswscale      2.  1.103 /  2.  1.103
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, image2, from '%04d.png':
  Duration: 00:00:26.12, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24, 1280x720, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[libx264 @ 0x7fcef882da00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x7fcef882da00] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 3.1, 4:4:4 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x7fcef882da00] 264 - core 125 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2012 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'vid.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf54.59.106
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv444p, 1280x720, q=-1--1, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png -> libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  782 fps= 38 q=-1.0 Lsize=    3630kB time=00:00:26.00 bitrate=1143.7kbits/s dup=129 drop=0    
video:3620kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.274990%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcef882da00] frame I:4     Avg QP:16.20  size: 99567
[libx264 @ 0x7fcef882da00] frame P:218   Avg QP:22.35  size: 13246
[libx264 @ 0x7fcef882da00] frame B:560   Avg QP:28.53  size:   750
[libx264 @ 0x7fcef882da00] consecutive B-frames:  4.3%  0.3%  0.8% 94.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcef882da00] mb I  I16..4: 20.5% 32.0% 47.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcef882da00] mb P  I16..4:  0.2%  0.6%  0.5%  P16..4: 17.3%  6.8%  5.8%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:68.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcef882da00] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8: 13.5%  0.4%  0.2%  direct: 0.4%  skip:85.5%  L0:36.6% L1:61.3% BI: 2.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcef882da00] 8x8 transform intra:41.0% inter:61.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcef882da00] coded y,u,v intra: 53.8% 3.2% 31.0% inter: 5.7% 0.0% 2.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcef882da00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 54% 40%  6%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcef882da00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 10% 18% 34%  6%  8%  7%  6%  6%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcef882da00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 13% 25% 21%  6%  9%  6% 10%  3%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcef882da00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcef882da00] ref P L0: 73.0%  9.8% 14.2%  3.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcef882da00] ref B L0: 89.7%  9.3%  1.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcef882da00] ref B L1: 91.2%  8.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7fcef882da00] kb/s:1137.38
```

Comment: The answer is the same I gave you on your previous question :) Try using another pixel format, e.g. `-pix_fmt yuv420p`, or use a player that supports H.264 4:4:4 (but I don't know one).

Comment: Ha should've guessed it was the same problem. Thanks again :)

Comment: Consider moving `-r 30` as an input option (before `-i`), otherwise ffmpeg will use the default of `-r 25` for the input and using `-r 30` for the output will result in duplicated frames: 129 in your case as indicated by your console output. However, there are cases where having different frame rates for input and output are needed.